# Swift Optionals - Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Tags: swift, option-type

I am new to Swift and trying to figure out the Optional concept. I have a small piece of code in Playground which is giving me "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" error. Can someone please explain why and how do I fix it?

I only want to print "Yes" or "No" depending on if "score1" has a value or not. Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa

class Person {
    var score1: Int? = 9

    func sum() {
        if let score1 {
            print("yes")
        } else {
            print("No")
        }
    }//end sum
 }// end person

 var objperson = person()
 objperson.sum()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The if let statement takes an optional variable. If it is nil, the else block or nothing is executed. If it has a value, the value is assigned to a different variable as a non-optional type.

So, the following code would output the value of score1 or "No" if there is none:

```
if let score1Unwrapped = score1
{
    print(score1Unwrapped)

}

else
{
    print("No")
}
```

A shorter version of the same would be:

```
print(score1 ?? "No")
```

In your case, where you don't actually use the value stored in the optional variable, you can also check if the value is nil:

```
if score1 != nil {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks LorenzSchaef - I basically arrived at the same conclusion.

Comment: Other option when not using the unwrapped value is: if let _ = score1 { ... }

Answer (score 5):

Writing

```
if let score1 {
```

doesn't make sense. If you want to see if score has a value, use

```
if score1 != nil {
```

or

```
if let score = score1 {
```

The last case binds a new non-optional constant `score` to `score1`. This lets you use `score` inside the if statement.

Comment: This is now valid since swift 5.7

Answer (score 3):

The code in your question is similar to something I saw in the swift book and documentation and they are correct.

Your playground is just using an old version of swift which currently doesn't support this syntax. Using a beta version of XCode should fix

https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/vy7jhx/unwrapping_optionals/

Comment: while this is true now, the the question was originally asked in 2015 before Swift would have added this new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `if let` assumes you want to create a constant `score1` with some value. If you just want to check if it contains a value, as in not `nil` you should just do it like below:

```
if score1! != nil {
     // println("yes")
```

So your full code would look like this:

```
class Person {
    var score1: Int? = 9

    func sum() {
        if score1 != nil {
            println("yes")
        }
        else {
            println("no")
        }
    }
}

var objperson = Person()
objperson.sum()
```

Comment: This isn't the idiom used in Swift for testing for nil.  The answers above, of the form "if let score1 = score { ..." are the way to go.  Note, the unwrapped variable can have the same name as the wrapped variable and that too has become the norm in Swift code.

Answer (score -1):

You can unwrap it using this:

```
import Cocoa

class Person {
    var score1: Int? = 9

    func sum() {
        print("\(score1 != nil ? "YES" : "NO")")
    }
 }
```

And then call it like:

```
 var objperson = Person()
 objperson.sum()
```

Comment: FYI - there is no unwrapping here. You are simply checking to see if it is nil or not. This is a perfectly valid answer other than misstating that you are using unwrapping. I suspect the old downvote is because this answer basically duplicates several much older answers suggesting simply comparing `score1` against `nil`.